# Get information from a form and writing to an xml file using php?

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

I want to get information from a form  and writing to an xml file by using php ? My xml file is in tree structure

Example of my xml file:

```
<BookStore>
    <Book>
        <name>TODO</name>
        <url>TODO</url>
    </Book>
</BookStore>
```

when I submit it will create a xml but I want `Book` and `BookStore` also as a parent. I created till `name` and `url`. But I dont know how to create `Book` and `BookStore` too?

Comment: Hi this is my php code from where i am able to create xml and to print name and url now i want book and bookstore also

Comment: '<?php
   $text = htmlentities($_POST['tb']);
   $text1 = htmlentities($_POST['tb1']);
   $doc = new DOMDocument( );
    $textareaNode = $doc->createElement("name");
    $textNode = $doc->createTextNode($text);
   $textareaNode->appendChild($textNode);
$textareaNode1 = $doc->createElement("url");
  $textNode1 = $doc->createTextNode($text1);
  $tectareaNode= $textareaNode1->appendChild($textNode1);
$doc->appendChild($textareaNode);
$doc->appendChild($textareaNode1);
$doc->save("d.xml");
 ?>'

Comment: I think the problem is in your php code. check it once

Comment: You should put your PHP into the question so it can be formatted and easier for us to read.

Comment: @VigneshBala: hi i dont know php code for hierarchy  like book or bookstore.. give me some idea.

Comment: @steve :- check i put php code till name and url i am able to print... but how i can do for hierarchy like book or bookstore.

Comment: Read this link it will help you @lucky http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/286802-appending-dynamic-data-to-existing-xml-file-in-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create new parent elements and then append the child.

```
$bookstore = $doc->createElement('Bookstore');
$book = $doc->createElement("Book");

/* your code */

/* append name and url to $book */
$book->appendChild($textareaNode);
$book->appendChild($textareaNode1); 
$bookstore->appendChild($book);
$doc->appendChild($bookstore);

$doc->save("d.xml");
```